# Dimensions are not Ok in matlab

Tags: matlab

When I take image from img from commands =

```
imread('C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Detect\F04U2MPIXQG15WQS.LARGE.jpg');

figure,imshow(img)
```

It works fine but when I use

```
[filename, pathname] = ...

uigetfile({'*.jpg';'*.jpeg';'*.png';'*.*'},'Select Image File');

img=strcat(pathname,filename);
```

> error shown is Error in skinDetect2Func (line 8)
>
> yuv(:,:,y) = (img(:,:,r)+2.*img(:,:,g)+img(:,:,b))/4; Error in
>   bwFingers1 (line 39)
>
> out=skinDetect2Func(img);

Anyone can help me out I am just stuck in here. :(

Here is the complete code:

```
function out=skinDetect2func(img)

imshow(img);

sz=size(img); r=1;g=2;b=3;y=1;u=2;v=3;

yuv=img;

region=yuv;

 yuv(:,:,y) = (img(:,:,r)+2.*img(:,:,g)+img(:,:,b))/4;

 yuv(:,:,u) = img(:,:,r)-img(:,:,g);

 yuv(:,:,v)=img(:,:,b)-img(:,:,g);

 region = (yuv(:,:,u)>20 & yuv(:,:,v)<74) .* 255;

toc;

out=region;


%filtering

out=im2bw(out); out=bwareaopen(out,100);

out=imdilate(out,strel('diamond',4));

%retain largest only

res=out;

cc=bwconncomp(res);

arr=(cellfun('length',cc.PixelIdxList));

newLabel=res;

if ~isempty(round(arr))

    msz=0;

    for i=1:length(arr)

        if msz<arr(i:i)

            msz=arr(i:i);

            index=i;

        end

    end

    labels=labelmatrix(cc);

    newLabel=(labels==index);

    out=newLabel;

end

out=imfill(out,'holes');

end***
```

Comment: Where is the actual error message? Or am I missing it?

Comment: It is index exceed the dimensions of the matrix

Comment: Check the size of the matrices on both sides of the equals sign. You'll see that they are not the same.

Comment: So how to sove this problem :(

Answer (score 0):

ehm,

This is a string:

```
img=strcat(pathname,filename); % STRing conCATenation
```

You still need to `imread`...

The correct code would be

```
imgpath=strcat(pathname,filename);
img=imread(imgpath);
```

Comment: Solved Thanks :)

Comment: @fahadyaseen consider accepting the answer as valid